# Unable to load my own classes

Tags: android, andengine

I'm currently building an app that has to interact with a server. I have some classes that are defined in the server that I need to use in my app. I've tried the following to import my classes.

1. Add the server project as a library for my app project
2. Export my server project into a jar file and then copy it to my app project and make it its library.

Both methods allowed me to not have any compile time errors, however, when running the app, whenever the app uses one of the classes referenced from server project it will crash.

I debugged and whenever I get to the class (of the server) it would jump to `Engine.class` in the method `onTickUpdate()` and then crash.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently, it can not find the class even if the class is fine during compile time.
Is it a common problem for android apps to have problem in linking external jar libraries?

Comment: [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/cyberycon/archive/2011/05/17/using-external-libraries-with-android.aspx)
I followed this but still not working....

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, that your server library is using some other java libraries, which you haven't exported from your android project.

At compile time, since you have those libraries in your build path, everything works fine, but the dex compiler will only export classes that you have explicitly marked for export.

You may want to check which reference is causing the app to crash, extract the class files from your apk, and see if that class is present or not.